# combine multiple documents in a couchdb view

Tags: couchdb

In couchdb, I need to represent some data in the following format, a outer container that references other documents inside an array.

I want to keep these documents separate as I need to manage conflicts on them individually.

```
{
  "_id" : "1"'
  "type" : "container",
  "items" : [ "1", "2", "3"]
}


{
   "_id" : "2",
   "value": "a"
    "type" : "item"
}


{
   "_id" : "3",
   "value": "b"
   "type" : "item"
 }


 {
   "_id" : "4",
   "value": "c"
    "type" : "item"
 }
```

I want to output a view of the data in the following format.

```
{
  "_id" : "1"'
  "type" : "container",
  "items" : [
     {
       "_id" : "2",
       "value": "a"
       "type" : "item"
     },
     {
       "_id" : "3",
       "value": "b"
       "type" : "item"
     },
     {
       "_id" : "4",
       "value": "c"
       "type" : "item"
     }
   ]

}
```

Whats the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this using [couchdb linked documents](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html)

here is how the view will look like

```
  function(doc){
    if(doc.items)
    doc.items.forEach(function(item){
          emit(doc._id,{_id:item});
      })
 }
```

now you can query the view with `include_docs=true` parameter and you should have the desired result.

Comment: Will this return a single document as above?

Comment: @AlanQuigley almost. The above view will return all the documents in the items array. You will have to extract the results out of the couchdb response though.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it to work using the list function to rewrite the document in the required format.